# Swift Playground doesn't recognize Cocoa Touch initializer

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I have this really simple and short code in a playground:

```
import Foundation
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: "key", options: kNilOptions)
```

but the playground doesn't like it and thinks I wanted to use the `init(bytes:length:)`. What is wrong there?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, the issue shown is:

```
Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:13:18: error: incorrect argument labels in call
(have 'base64EncodedString:options:', expected 'bytes:length:')
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: "key", options: kNilOptions)
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~         ~~~~~~~
              bytes                       length
```

Comment: You are trying to create data from non encoded string and so the app crashes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSDataBase64DecodingOptions` is a `RawOptionSetType` which inherits from 
`NilLiteralConvertible`, therefore you can specify `nil` for "no options":

```
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQNCg==", options: nil)
```

**Update: As of Swift 2,** NS_OPTIONS types get imported as conforming to the  `OptionSetType` protocol, which presents a set-like interface for options. "No options" can be specified as the empty set:

```
let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: "SGVsbG8gd29ybGQNCg==", options: [])
```

Comment: Thanks, missed that. Was used to Objective-C style options

Comment: @DavideDeFranceschi: Yes, it is confusing that `nil` in Swift can denote something "scalar" and not necessarily a pointer. Btw. `options: .allZeros` as indicated in the other answer would work as well, because `RawOptionSetType` also inherits from `BitwiseOperationsType`.

Answer (score 1):

The method is used to create a plain data from base64 encoded string. So, this method does not accept utf-8 or ascii encoded string.

```
let encodedData = "key".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

let base64EncodedString = encodedData?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.allZeros)


let data = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64EncodedString!, options:.allZeros)
```

// you can retrieve the reverse string using the

```
let originalString = String(NSString(data: theData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

println(originalString)
```

Comment: I used that `"key"` string only as example, the problem was in the compilation itself

Comment: (You can abbreviate that to `options: .allZeros`.)